# Scanning a webpage in java and downloading the first image that appears on it?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm working on a console application that gets input from a user on a songname, a songartist, and the album. I'm trying to make it search for it with the info that it pulled in from the user and then download the first image that appears on google images! Then it searches google for those results, pulls the first image and then it can be added to an mp3 file, (I probably will add some functionality where it reads files automatically from a selected directory and reads the names then spits out album art :) ) If I'm not clear I can elaborate more if needed, thanks so much for your time and if you have any tips for my code please pitch in!

My code:

```
package j1media.main;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Core {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String songName;
        String songArtist;
        String songAlbum;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the song you'd like a cover to Add a + for a space: ");
        songName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Song name " + songName + " recorded, please enter the artist: ");
        songArtist = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(songName + " by " + songArtist + " has been recorded, please enter the album(Type Y for n/a): ");
        songAlbum = input.nextLine();
        URL website = new URL("https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + songName + "+by+" + songArtist + "&FORM=HDRSC2");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream getImage = new FileOutputStream(songName + "art");
        getImage.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: And also in advanced, I understand there is no functionality in typing Y for n/a, it hasn't been added in yet, thanks!

Comment: How the title is related to the content?

Comment: You're supposed to ask a question. What is it?

Comment: Guys, the question is how can I scan the webpage and download the first image that appears on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad for this site.

But here are a few pointers to possible solutions:

- Look for an IMG tag in the response using a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
- Parse the HTML response, then traverse the node tree and look for an IMG node.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the second option, sorry for being so broad.